# Notification tray count is wrong

Tags: windows-10, notification-area

The notification tray icon shows the wrong count:

[image]

As a temporary workaround to the annoyance of this I thought I would disable the count. This menu option has no effect at all:

[image]

Is this a known defect in the current build of Windows 10 (Version 1803, Build 17134.284)? I can't find anything on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: It is not a known default to my knowledge. I support a few hundred desktops running 1803 and none have exhibited this behavior.

Comment: @Ramhound Applying the available Windows updates appears to have corrected the behavior.  I won't know if the updates themselves patched a defect, or if simply having updated OS files resolved it.  In either case, thanks for the suggestion.  It's strange that those did not automatically install as they have in the past.

Comment: @Ramhound I installed KB4458469 as soon as it was available and the problem is still there.

Comment: @Yuck the reboot temporary solves the problem but after a while it reappears.

Comment: @jj_ Same for me - this problem still exists.  I've given up and just live with it.  Very annoying bug.  I believe it might have something to do with the Windows 10 LinkedIn app.

Comment: @Yuck I don't think so, I am not using Win 10 LinkedIn app. 
I think MS actually thought they fixed with latest update, but they must have missed some other causing condition.

Answer (score -3):

Try to right-click the Action Center icon and select
"Don't show number of new notifications".

Then repeat the same procedure with the newly named "Show number of new notifications".

EDIT : Apparently no longer works.

Comment: Doesn't work, and when right clicking again the string still says: "Don't show number of new notifications"

Comment: It used to work - I tested it before posting. Windows changes all the time.